# Rails - Render HTML output from Database

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a working form which stores data in my database and I can get this data and display it on my site.

I now want to store HTML code directly in the database to enable styling. For example I want my title to have a h3 format. I can write this into my form and it will be stored to the database.

```
<h3>Test Title</h3>
```

But when I display the output of this form it shows the h3 tag in cleartext (of course). I want to know how to render this as html code? Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= raw @html_source %>
```

I like to note that raw is more "user-friendly" than html_safe, because it silently output an empty string for nil too. While html_safe would throw

> *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `html_safe' for
>   nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

or you can declare the string as html_safe:

```
my_string.html_safe
```